# How to draw a braid of long exact sequences

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

For example, in page 353 of Ranicki's book [Algebraic and geometric surgery](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/surgery.pdf),

there is a braid of long exact sequences like so:

[image]

I use xy-pic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AndrewStacey is on his way :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Remarks

The same as @daleif's answer, just with `tikz-cd` instead of `xy-pic`. Have fun!

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={minimum width=1.5cm}}]% to make it more symmetric
    L_{m+1}(\mathbb{Z}) \arrow[bend left]{rr} \arrow{rd}
    &
    & \Theta_m \arrow[bend left]{rr}{0} \arrow{rd}
    &
    & \pi_m(BO) \arrow[bend left]{rr} \arrow{rd}
    &
    & \Omega^{fr}_{m-1}
    \\
%
    & \Theta^{fr}_{m} \arrow{ru} \arrow{rd}
    &
    & A_m \arrow{ru} \arrow{rd}
    &
    & \Theta^{fr}_{m-1} \arrow{ru} \arrow{rd}
    &
    \\
%
    \pi_m(O) \arrow[bend right]{rr}{J} \arrow{ru}
    &
    & \Omega^{fr}_m \arrow[bend right]{rr}{\sigma^*} \arrow{ru}
    &
    & L_m(\mathbb{Z}) \arrow[bend right]{rr} \arrow{ru}
    &
    & \Theta_{m-1}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: much nicer arrowheads ;-)

Comment: @daleif `tikz-cd` (and `tikz` as well) automatically uses the arrowhead of the standard Computer Modern `\rightarrow`, to match the equations. You can still customize the arrowheads by adding `/tikz/commutative diagrams/diagrams={>=*<arrow head>*}` to either `\tikzset` or to the parameters of the drawing.

Comment: @daleif -- if you choose the option `[cmtip]` for `xy` you'll get the "nicer" arrowheads.  not sure why, but `[all]` doesn't do it.

Answer (score 12):

That brings back memories. But here is the basic structure. From the `xy` guide you will learn how to make the arrows curve more (if needed)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
A \ar[rd] \ar@/^/[rr] &
&
C \ar[rd] \ar@/^/[rr] &
&
E \ar[rd] \ar@/^/[rr] &
&
G \\
&
B \ar[ur] \ar[dr] &
&
D \ar[ur] \ar[dr]&
&
F \ar[ur] \ar[dr]&
\\
A \ar[ur] \ar@/_/[rr]^J &
&
C \ar[ur] \ar@/_/[rr]^{\sigma_*} &
&
E \ar[ur] \ar@/_/[rr] &
&
G \\
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Decreasing the row spacing may help: `\xymatrix@R-1pc{...` or so.

Answer (score 4):

Another [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) option, but using `matrix of nodes`.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% make the arrows look like stealth fighter jets
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix[name=M, matrix of nodes,cells={nodes={minimum width=1.5cm}}, column sep=1.5cm, row sep=1cm]{
        $L_{m+1}(\mathbb{Z})$ &                & $\Theta_m$      &       & $\pi_m(BO)$       &                    & $\Omega_{m-1}^{fr}$ \\
                              &$\Theta_m^{fr}$ &                 & $A_m$ &                   & $\Theta_{m-1}^{fr}$& \\ 
        $\pi_m(O)$            &                & $\Omega_m^{fr}$ &       & $L_m(\mathbb{Z})$ &                    & $\Theta_{m-1}$ \\
    };
    % straight edges
    \foreach \start/\end in {
        M-1-1/M-2-2,
        M-3-1/M-2-2,
        M-2-2/M-1-3,
        M-2-2/M-3-3,
        M-1-3/M-2-4,
        M-3-3/M-2-4,
        M-2-4/M-1-5,
        M-2-4/M-3-5,
        M-1-5/M-2-6,
        M-3-5/M-2-6,
        M-2-6/M-1-7,
    M-2-6/M-3-7}
    {
        \draw[->] (\start) edge (\end);
    }
    % curved arrows
    \draw[->] (M-1-1) to[out=30,in=150] (M-1-3);
    \draw[->] (M-1-3) to[out=30,in=150] node[pos=0.5,above]{$0$} (M-1-5);
    \draw[->] (M-1-5) to[out=30,in=150]  (M-1-7);
    \draw[->] (M-3-1) to[out=-30,in=-150] node[pos=0.5,above]{$J$} (M-3-3);
    \draw[->] (M-3-3) to[out=-30,in=-150] node[pos=0.5,above]{$\sigma^*$} (M-3-5);
    \draw[->] (M-3-5) to[out=-30,in=-150] (M-3-7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```